# Rand Index function (clustering performance evaluation)

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, precision, unsupervised-learning

As far as I know, there is no package available for Rand Index in python while for Adjusted Rand Index you have the option of using `sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred)`.

I wrote the code for Rand Score and I am going to share it with others as the answer to the post.

Comment: Why would one use the non-adjusted Rand index?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse This is a method which is used in some papers. Most of the times, both methods have been implemented and reported in a result table. However, I agree that ARI is a better indicator in most cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from scipy.misc import comb
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

def check_clusterings(labels_true, labels_pred):
    """Check that the two clusterings matching 1D integer arrays."""
    labels_true = np.asarray(labels_true)
    labels_pred = np.asarray(labels_pred)    
    # input checks
    if labels_true.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError(
            "labels_true must be 1D: shape is %r" % (labels_true.shape,))
    if labels_pred.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError(
            "labels_pred must be 1D: shape is %r" % (labels_pred.shape,))
    if labels_true.shape != labels_pred.shape:
        raise ValueError(
            "labels_true and labels_pred must have same size, got %d and %d"
            % (labels_true.shape[0], labels_pred.shape[0]))
    return labels_true, labels_pred

def rand_score (labels_true, labels_pred):
"""given the true and predicted labels, it will return the Rand Index."""
    check_clusterings(labels_true, labels_pred)
    my_pair = list(combinations(range(len(labels_true)), 2)) #create list of all combinations with the length of labels.
    def is_equal(x):
        return (x[0]==x[1])
    my_a = 0
    my_b = 0
    for i in range(len(my_pair)):
            if(is_equal((labels_true[my_pair[i][0]],labels_true[my_pair[i][1]])) == is_equal((labels_pred[my_pair[i][0]],labels_pred[my_pair[i][1]])) 
               and is_equal((labels_pred[my_pair[i][0]],labels_pred[my_pair[i][1]])) == True):
                my_a += 1
            if(is_equal((labels_true[my_pair[i][0]],labels_true[my_pair[i][1]])) == is_equal((labels_pred[my_pair[i][0]],labels_pred[my_pair[i][1]])) 
               and is_equal((labels_pred[my_pair[i][0]],labels_pred[my_pair[i][1]])) == False):
                my_b += 1
    my_denom = comb(len(labels_true),2)
    ri = (my_a + my_b) / my_denom
    return ri
```

As a simple example:

```
labels_true = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
labels_pred = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
rand_score (labels_true, labels_pred)
#0.46666666666666667
```

There are probably some ways to improve it and make it more pythonic. If you have any suggestion, you may improve it.

I found [this implementation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/rand-index-calculation) which seems faster.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import comb
def rand_index_score(clusters, classes):
    tp_plus_fp = comb(np.bincount(clusters), 2).sum()
    tp_plus_fn = comb(np.bincount(classes), 2).sum()
    A = np.c_[(clusters, classes)]
    tp = sum(comb(np.bincount(A[A[:, 0] == i, 1]), 2).sum()
             for i in set(clusters))
    fp = tp_plus_fp - tp
    fn = tp_plus_fn - tp
    tn = comb(len(A), 2) - tp - fp - fn
    return (tp + tn) / (tp + fp + fn + tn)
```

As a simple example:

```
labels_true = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
labels_pred = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
rand_index_score (labels_true, labels_pred)
#0.46666666666666667
```

Comment: @theausome I take back my comment.

Comment: Looks like a very slow code for me. If you run this on a larger data set, how long does it take? Compared to the ARI implementation?

Comment: For sure it is slower since it includes a for loop which does not exist in ARI. If you have any suggestion to improve it, please either comment or add an answer. I convert it from the similar R code. @Anony-Mousse

Comment: It shouldn't be slower than ARI, which includes the computation of the RI.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from scikit-learn 0.24.0, the `sklearn.metrics.rand_score` function has been added, implementing the (unadjusted) Rand index. Please check the [changelog](https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/whats_new/v0.24.html#version-0-24-0).

All you have to do is:

```
from sklearn.metrics import rand_score

rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred)
```

`labels_true` and `labels_pred` can have values in different domains. For example:

```
>>> rand_score(['a', 'b', 'c'], [5, 6, 7])
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
def rand_index_score(y_gold, y_predict):
    index1_index2_pairs = list(it.combinations(range(len(y_gold)), 2)) #create list of all combinations with the length of labels.
    numberOfPairs = len(index1_index2_pairs)
    fractalUpperPart = 0

    for index1_index2 in index1_index2_pairs:
        theyRealyAreInSameGroup = y_gold[index1_index2[0]] == y_gold[index1_index2[1]]
        itIsPredictedThatTheyAreInSameGroup =  y_predict[index1_index2[0]] == y_predict[index1_index2[1]]

        if theyRealyAreInSameGroup == itIsPredictedThatTheyAreInSameGroup:
            fractalUpperPart += 1
   
    return fractalUpperPart/numberOfPairs
```